# Amazon MQ High Storage Percentage

Tags: activemq-classic, amazon-mq

We currently use active/standby Amazon MQ (ActiveMQ) brokers in our architecture. We have been noticing that our storage has been constantly been increasing over time which is slowing down our broker performance and causing long reboot times. We currently use VirtualTopics with 4 consumers for each topic

I've checked the queues and none of them have any large number of pending messages. The consumers are all fast enough to grab the messages and process them. The only queue that has around 40,000 messages is the DLQ. However, we also tried to delete the messages in that queue and the storage used still did not decrease.

I have reached out to Amazon Support but I did not receive a useful answer.

**I would just like to understand if there is a way to understand what queue/topic is occupying the storage so that we could purge the messages and reduce the storage for better performance and faster reboots.**

Our configuration

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<broker schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="10000" xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">
  <!--
  A configuration contains all of the settings for your ActiveMQ broker, in XML format (similar to ActiveMQ's activemq.xml file).
  You can create a configuration before creating any brokers. You can then apply the configuration to one or more brokers.

  You can use additional attributes for the broker element above. These attributes allow you to configure broker-wide settings.

  For more information, see Configuration and Amazon MQ Broker Configuration Parameters in the Amazon MQ Developer Guide:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/amazon-mq-broker-configuration-parameters.html
  -->
  <!--
  Mirrored queues let you send a copy of each message to a topic with a similar name automatically.
  For more information, see http://activemq.apache.org/mirrored-queues.html

  Virtual destinations let you configure advanced routing of messages between destinations.
  For more information, see http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html
  -->
  <!--
  <destinationInterceptors>
    <mirroredQueue copyMessage="true" postfix=".qmirror" prefix=""/>
    <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
      <virtualDestinations>
        <virtualTopic name="&gt;" prefix="VirtualTopicConsumers.*." selectorAware="false"/>
        <compositeQueue name="MY.QUEUE">
          <forwardTo>
            <queue physicalName="FOO"/>
            <topic physicalName="BAR"/>
          </forwardTo>
        </compositeQueue>
      </virtualDestinations>
    </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
  </destinationInterceptors>
  -->
  <!--
  By default, Amazon MQ optimizes for queues with fast consumers:
  Consumers are considered fast if they are able to keep up with the rate of messages generated by producers.
  Consumers are considered slow if a queue builds up a backlog of unacknowledged messages, potentially causing a decrease in producer throughput.
  To instruct Amazon MQ to optimize for queues with slow consumers, set the concurrentStoreAndDispatchQueues attribute to false.
  For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/ensuring-effective-amazon-mq-performance.html
  -->
  <persistenceAdapter>
    <kahaDB concurrentStoreAndDispatchQueues="false"/>
  </persistenceAdapter>
  <destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
      <policyEntries>
        <!--
        gcInactiveDestinations is used to automatically purge inactive destinations
        preventing them from unnecessarily using broker resources.

        An 'inactive' destination is one that has no messages pending and no consumers connected.

        For more information, see: http://activemq.apache.org/delete-inactive-destinations.html
        -->
        <policyEntry gcInactiveDestinations="true" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="600000" topic="&gt;">
          <!--
          The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
          slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
          by limiting the number of messages that are retained

          For more information, see: http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html
          -->
          <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
            <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
          </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
        </policyEntry>
        <policyEntry gcInactiveDestinations="true" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="600000" queue="&gt;"/>
        <!--
        Destination policies let you configure a rich set of behaviors for your queues and topics.
        For more information, see http://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies.html
        -->
        <!--
        <policyEntry topic="FOO.&gt;">
          <dispatchPolicy>
            <roundRobinDispatchPolicy/>
          </dispatchPolicy>
          <subscriptionRecoveryPolicy>
            <lastImageSubscriptionRecoveryPolicy/>
          </subscriptionRecoveryPolicy>
        </policyEntry>
        <policyEntry advisoryForConsumed="true" tempTopic="true"/>
        <policyEntry advisoryForConsumed="true" tempQueue="true"/>
        -->
      </policyEntries>
    </policyMap>
  </destinationPolicy>
  <!--
  Typically, destinations are created automatically when they are used. Amazon MQ lets you create destinations when the broker is started.
  For more information, see http://activemq.apache.org/configure-startup-destinations.html
  -->
  <!--
  <destinations>
    <queue physicalName="FOO.BAR"/>
    <topic physicalName="SOME.TOPIC"/>
  </destinations>
  -->
  <!--
  You can control advanced ActiveMQ features using plugins.
  -->
  <plugins>
    <!--
    The Authorization plugin allows you to control the groups of users that are allowed to perform certain operations on your destinations.
    For more information, see http://activemq.apache.org/security.html
    -->
    <!--
    <authorizationPlugin>
      <map>
        <authorizationMap>
          <authorizationEntries>
            <authorizationEntry admin="guests,users" queue="GUEST.&gt;" read="guests" write="guests,users"/>
            <authorizationEntry admin="guests,users" read="guests,users" topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.&gt;" write="guests,users"/>
          </authorizationEntries>
          <tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry>
            <tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry admin="tempDestinationAdmins" read="tempDestinationAdmins" write="tempDestinationAdmins"/>
          </tempDestinationAuthorizationEntry>
        </authorizationMap>
      </map>
    </authorizationPlugin>
    -->
    <!--
    The Discarding DLQ plugin simplifies the configuration of your global dead-letter queue strategy.
    You can take advantage of a more granular per-destination control by using destination policies.
    For more information, see http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html
    -->
    <!--
    <discardingDLQBrokerPlugin dropAll="true" dropTemporaryQueues="true" dropTemporaryTopics="true"/>
    -->
    <!--
    The Force Persistency Mode plugin can override the persistency mode set on messages.
    -->
    <!--
    <forcePersistencyModeBrokerPlugin persistenceFlag="true"/>
    -->
    <!--
    The Redelivery plugin extends the capabilities of destination policies with respect to message redelivery.
    For more information, see http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html
    -->
    <!--
    <redeliveryPlugin fallbackToDeadLetter="true" sendToDlqIfMaxRetriesExceeded="true">
      <redeliveryPolicyMap>
        <redeliveryPolicyMap>
          <redeliveryPolicyEntries>
            <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="4" queue="SpecialQueue" redeliveryDelay="60000"/>
          </redeliveryPolicyEntries>
          <defaultEntry>
            <redeliveryPolicy initialRedeliveryDelay="45000" maximumRedeliveries="4" redeliveryDelay="60000"/>
          </defaultEntry>
        </redeliveryPolicyMap>
      </redeliveryPolicyMap>
    </redeliveryPlugin>
    -->
    <!--
    The Statistics plugin lets you query broker or destination statistics by sending messages to the broker.
    For more information, see http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html
    -->
    <!--
    <statisticsBrokerPlugin/>
    -->
    <!--
    The Timestamping plugin lets the broker use server-side time instead of client-provided time for messages.
    For more information, see http://activemq.apache.org/timestampplugin.html
    -->
    <!--
    <timeStampingBrokerPlugin ttlCeiling="86400000" zeroExpirationOverride="86400000"/>
    -->
  </plugins>
  <!--
  Network connectors let you connect brokers into networks of brokers.
  For more information, see Creating and Configuring an Amazon MQ Network of Brokers
  (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/amazon-mq-creating-configuring-network-of-brokers.html)
  in the Amazon MQ Developer Guide and also Networks of Brokers
  (http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html) in the ActiveMQ documentation.
  -->
  <!--
  <networkConnectors>
    <networkConnector name="myNetworkConnector" userName="commonUser" uri="masterslave:(ssl://b-1a2b3c4d-1.mq.region.amazonaws.com:61617,ssl://b-1a2b3c4d-2.mq.region.amazonaws.com:61617)"/>
  </networkConnectors>
  -->
</broker>
```

Comment: What answer did Amazon provide that wasn't useful?

Answer (score 3):

More than likely, it's the 40k messages in the DLQ. Do not use your message broker as long term storage; that's not what it is meant for.

As an oversimplified explanation: KahaDB writes a bunch of data stripes, then as the messages are consumed from each data stripe, it can GC a data stripe. It can only GC the data stripe once all messages stored in that stripe are consumed. If you have a bunch of old messages lying around, it can never GC those data stripes from disk.

This can happen with *any* queue that has really old messages in it. Consume or discard messages as soon as possible. Treat the DLQ with urgency, or don't use it at all; disable the DLQ in your configuration and let errors evaporate, having a business process to look for errors elsewhere.

In certain scenarios, moving the messages to another queue and back can allow KahaDB to do some compaction, but a lot of asterisks apply here as it has to be in two separate transactions and there are risks there. The best advice remains: Brokers are not storage devices.

If the DLQ is not important, as in: you can just delete messages without recourse, then you most likely don't need persistent delivery, as each message isn't really that important. If 100% reliability is not needed, you can turn off persistent delivery and then the messages won't *necessarily* be written out to disk. This may also improve the situation, but turning persistent delivery off is dependent on your business requirements and how you are using messaging in your stack.

Finally, if all of your queues are empty, you can shutdown your broker and empty out the data directory, then start it again. This will cause KahaDB to start over. This is a short term fix though, as the root of the problem (Not handling DLQs) will likely still remain.